# After install phpMyAdmin, I could not access phpMyAdmin from web Browser - 404 Page Not Found?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I tried to install apache2, php, mysql, and phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu by following this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKICJgdHz-8) video. After awhile it seemed apache2, php, and mysql were working fine. However I have problem with phpMyAdmin, that when I tried to access it from address `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, browser show 404 page not found.

I don't know what caused this problem, but I was ensure mysql was working as I could access mysql shell from terminal `mysql -u root -proot`. Furthermore, I tried to test run php file by creating `infor.php` inside `/var/www/html` and run from browser `http://localhost/infor.php`, it is also not working.

What is the problem with that? Am I missing something? Please kindly help. Thanks

Comment: 'It seemed Apache was working', how did you check? Does localhost run?

Comment: Are they installed separately or as Xampp / Lampp bundle? Have you checked the location of the phpmyadmin index.html file? What error did the php file give?